# Converting float32 to bit-equivalent int32

Tags: python, image, types, binary, type-conversion

The Pillow module in Python insists on opening a 32-bit/pixel TIFF file I have as if the pixels were of type float32, whereas I believe the correct interpretation is unsigned int32.  If I go ahead and load the data into a 640x512 array of type float32, how can I retype it as uint32 while preserving the underlying binary representation?

In Fortran and C, it's easy to have pointers or data structures of different type pointing to the same block of physical memory so that the raw memory contents can be easily be interpreted according to whatever type I want.  Is there an equivalent procedure in Python?

Sample follows (note that I have no information about compression etc.; the file in question was extracted by a commercial software program from a proprietary file format):

```
from PIL import Image

infile = "20181016_071207_367_R.tif"        
im = Image.open(infile)

data = np.array(im.getdata())
print(data)
```

> [ -9.99117374 -10.36103535  -9.80696869 ... -18.41988373 -18.35027885
>    -18.69905663]

Comment: Could you please add a reproducible example, or at least more detail to your question? Is it a compressed TIFF image? How are you opening the image and how do you know that Pillow is opening the image as float?

Comment: See added sample code.

Comment: But please note that my question was intended to be generic anyway (not dependent on the TIF file):  how, in general, does one alter the interpretation of binary data in a Python data structure (e.g., a numpy array)?

Comment: With a little testing, it seems that 32-bit float is a valid TIFF format for grayscale images. Is it possible that the TIFF file is in fact float and that Pillow and numpy are doing the right thing? Try plotting the array to see if it reproduces the image.

Comment: As for casting data structures like you would in C, you can use the [Python `struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/struct.html) module for that.

Comment: Would it make sense for a TIF file to encode thermal IR data as a negative floating point value?  I had expected an unsigned integer value that would need to scaled and offset to yield a positive brightness temperature in Kelvin.  EDIT:  It just occurred to me that the file might have already had the scaling applied and that the stored values are temperature in Celsius -- negative for values below freezing.  The floating point values do plot as an image, I just found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have `im.mode` originally equal to `F`, you can force Pillow to re-load the same data under a different mode (an very unusual desire indeed) in a somewhat hackish way like that:

```
imnew = im.convert(mode='I')
imnew.frombytes(im.tobytes())
```

More generally (outside the context of PIL), whenever you encounter the need to deal with raw memory representation in Python, you should usually rely on `numpy` or Python's built-in `memoryview` class with the `struct` module.

Here is an example of reinterpreting an array of numpy `float32` as `int32`:

```
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0], dtype='float32')
a_as_int32 = a.view('int32')
```

Here is an example of doing the same using `memoryview`:

```
# Create a memory buffer
b = bytearray(4*3)

# Write three floats
struct.pack_into('fff', b, 0, *[1.0, 2.0, 3.0])

# View the same memory as three ints
mem_as_ints = memoryview(b).cast('I')
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in this case, is that Pillow is loading the image with the correct type (float 32) as specified in the image exported from the thermal camera. There is no need to cast the image to integer, and doing so would cause an incorrect result.

Comment: The TIF image was the context for my question, but it was not the question.